# Why can't users upload files in this asset?

Tags: assets, users

I've two user groups; admin and user. The User group does not have access to the Assets tab, which stops them from just browsing all the assets that anyone might have uploaded - which is what I want; no random looking about in the Assets resources.

I've a field type 'Featured Image' that is an asset; and it is restricted to a single upload folder, file type image, with an upload location set to {slug} - this means it will upload files into a folder named the same as the slug for the entry in which it's being used.

It works fine for admins who have privileges to see Assets. I can not upload anything in this field with a user of type User.

This behaviour makes Asset fields essentially useless unless the user group also has privileges to view (and upload/edit) all assets site-wide. Because 'upload' is a child privilege of 'view assets' I can't give the upload rights without also giving them 'browse all the assets everywhere' rights.

I'd like these restricted users to be able to upload in that field.

Oddly, I have a Matrix field called Gallery which has an asset field inside it, set to file type image, single upload directory; {owner.slug}/gallery/

That asset field works fine for these users, and they are able to upload into it.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'd hoped this would be fixed in 2.3, alas it seems not, unless there's something I need to change?

Here's my experience as a mini screencast, logged in as a restricted user type (no assets privileges): http://viewcreative.co.uk/DELETEME/uploading.gif And here's the filetype set up and permissions: http://viewcreative.co.uk/DELETEME/permissions.gif

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [user group permission settings page](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users#user-groups)? There you should be able to select which Asset Sources users in a specific user group are able to view, upload files to, etc. If at least one Asset Source is selected then the Assets navigation item will appear for users in that group, otherwise it will be hidden.

[image: Asset Source permissions]

Comment: That's the problem; I do not want to have users allowed to access all *other users* asset resources - which this does. I want them to be able to upload files, but not view these sources. That's not an applicable option from what I can tell.

Comment: I.e., I want each user silo'd into their own folders. I do not want them able to see other resources belonging to anyone else. This works with how it's set up with the exeption that they can't upload assets *except* in a Matrix field.

Comment: @MattWilcox how does this work in a Matrix field? Does the modal show the asset source panel on the left? Or is there a special *upload only modal*, that doesn't show anything besides the red upload button?

Comment: That's where I think the problem lies, it's the proper UI for the function you're requesting, that is still missing. I think all you can do is to make a feature request for it.

Comment: if you check the "Restrict uploads to a single folder?" field and then set the "path to subfolder" to {author.username} then you should be able to restrict folders to the the entry's author. or {currentUser.username} may be better depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BenCroker - that is how it is set up already. I can't upload files as a member of Users, unless I give Users the 'View Source' privilege; which then adds the Assets tab and they can view everything. Not what I want. :(

Comment: Here's my experience as a mini screencast, logged in as a restricted user type (no assets privileges):
http://viewcreative.co.uk/DELETEME/uploading.gif

And here's the filetype set up and permissions:
http://viewcreative.co.uk/DELETEME/permissions.gif

Comment: ok i see. probably best to report this as a possible bug (or inconsistency) to P&T.